# row of 'LED's flashing one after the other?

Tags: android, class, view, android-activity

my main activity makes a new class that contains a thread.
i need to have a row of images where they change to the 'on' image in sequence, or even change the visibility or whatever.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

private TheSounds sound;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //the sound engine
        sound = new TheSounds(this);
```

and the class with the thread in it

```
public class TheSounds {
public Thread t;
public TheSounds(final myActivity testActivity){
t = new Thread(){
             public void run() {
              while(true) {
                                    //somevariable++;
```

so the idea is to have some variable representing the image to change.
The problem ive had is getting a reference to anything in the View from this thread.
i can give more info if you need it
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to either somehow pass a reference to your activity to the class with the thread and then you can call myActivity.runOnUiThread, passing it a runnable to use.

The better way to do this though is to use an `AsyncTask` which allows for convenient threading and allows for making changes to the UI in `onPostExecute`

See docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: thanks for his info. though i have no idea what you are saying lol. those developer.android docs are pretty much jibberish atm also. would you have code examples? cheers